# To notate a weekday schedule like "M-F" or "M~F", what is more commonly used, a hyphen "-" or tilde "~"?

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, hyphenation

I ask this under the assumption that "M-F" and "M~F" are the most commonly preferred notations for abbreviation weekday schedules if using 3-letter abbreviations like "Mon" and "Fri" take up too much space.

Alternatives that I can think of include:

> MTWTF

and

> MTWRF

I wonder what is most commonly used, the hyphen or tilde. It's difficult to perform a Google search to count the number of results because it doesn't seem like Google Search can search up punctuation marks.

Comment: Where have you seen a tilde?

Answer (score 4):

In English, tilde isn't used to represent a range. A [dash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) (specifically an en dash) is used in ranges of years, so would be appropriate here.

Informally, and as we don't have dashes on our keyboards, the hyphen-minus sign is a common and easy option. For historical reasons one symbol serves for both in many cases, but the hyphen and the minus sign aren't the same.

A tilde is sometimes used to indicate approximation in English text, but in some other languages it's used instead of ± (and sometimes makes its way into English as a result).

Mon-Fri is probably the most common compact way of expressing the range you want (I used a hyphen-minus there) but M-F is certainly seen.
Your MTWRF looks like a typo but it can't be because you present it as different to MTWTF. That's one to avoid.

Comment: Some places use R for Thursday [and N for Sunday] in order to have single-letter representations for all the days of the week.  But of course don't use it unless you are in one of those places.

Comment: @GEdgar don't use it unless you *and all your readers* are in such a place.

Comment: Mon-Fri is best. We never use the tilde.